# Flask keep running after closing terminal

Tags: python, flask

I'm running since yesterday a Flask web application on Windows in dev mode through command line : "env FLASK_APP=theflaskapp.py python -m flask run".

Everything was going well untill today, Flask run the same code even if I change some code lines and it keeps running even if I close the terminal. I don't understand why.

Maybe you can help me, please !

Comment: Did you try clearing your `*.pyc` files? I'm not sure if this can be the problem

Comment: Yes *.pyc files are creatde and stored in __pycache__ folders, I deleted them I it doesn't worked

Comment: How do you know its still running after closing the terminal?

Comment: visiting http://127.0.0.1:5000 and the same code is running even if I change it.